# adding css class to form component in cq5

Tags: forms, aem

I am creating a form component in cq5 by including parsys. I added text fields to it with a label and text field. Now, to add css class to the label and text fields, I edited it with the edit dialog for the text field but the css class i give in it, does not reflect on the text field. Can you please tel me what went wrong in adding css class to the text field in the form.

Answer (score 2):

For adding a CSS-style to component you need to create a directory in the hierarchy of components under the node of your component and name it "clientlibs". At this directory you need create two files: "css.txt" and file with the styles. More details can be found at these links:

[CQ5 Clientlib explained by example](http://blogs.adobe.com/livecycle/2012/02/cq5-clientlib-explained-by-example.html)
[Building Components in Adobe CQ 5 – Part 1: A tutorial on clientlibs using jQuery UI](http://blogs.adobe.com/mtg/2011/11/building-components-in-adobe-cq-5-part-1-a-tutorial-on-clientlibs-using-jquery-ui.html)